# Sign up that turns into a redirect doesn't send you back to the right page

Tags: bug, login

Here is what can currently happen today:

I'm not logged into SO.  I go to a question, I click "up vote". it shows the dialog "Thanks for the feedback!...Sign up or login..."

I click "Sign up using Stack Exchange"

It directs me to /users/signup?returnUrl=XXX

I then click on the log in tab (it redirects me to /users/signup with no GET parameters) and I login.

What I expect to happen:
It should take me back to the page I was on and trying to click the up button on.

What happens:
It takes me back to the SO home page and I have to use my browser's back button about 3 times to get back where I wanted, causing some confusion and enough consternation to justify me noting it on meta.

Suggested fix:
If you're on the "sign up" tab with a returnUrl GET param, keep/propagate that to the "Log in" tab if they switch to it.

Comment: 2nd bug report: "The page doesn't scroll back to the post I voted on".  3rd bug report: "I have to move the mouse back to the vote button".  4th bug report: "What is the point of navigating back to the page, I already voted".

Comment: Suggested fix: Log in before you vote. Problem solved.

Comment: This seems more reasonable when interpreted as a feature request than as a bug report. What about the UI led you to believe you would be directed to any particular page after logging in?

Comment: @AirThomas They both seemed like "tabs" of the same authentication page used before returning back to the original question page, FWIW.  One tab works ("sign up"), however the other ends up not doing so...

Comment: I guess that's fair enough. I wouldn't call it a bug, myself, but at this point it's just semantics. Upvoted you anyway.

Answer (score 12):

You're getting an unexpected result because you chose the wrong option from the pop-in window on the question page.

The solution is to use the "log in" link rather than the "sign up" buttons:

[image]

As I said in the comments, I think this is totally reasonable as a feature request to retain the `returnURL` value when switching from the "Sign up" tab to the "Log in" tab. I have to admit, I've made the same mistake; my eye gravitates much more strongly toward the buttons than to the link.

Comment: yes the log in link works "as expected" however sometimes I'm too quick on the trigger (or is it the verbiage "Sign up" that confuses me somehow? Hard to tell) and go through the Sign up route, which happens to also offers login functionality by just switching tabs, FWIW.

Comment: IMO the most user-friendly thing to do would be to provide one set of buttons that handles both new and returning users. The two tabs are almost identical anyway. But this may have been a calculated decision to maximize convenience for the new user at the expense of the returning user.